# Operator LIKE not working

Tags: php, mysql

i have the following php code:

```
$sth = "SELECT * FROM data WHERE titulo LIKE '%$input%'";

$rec = mysql_query($sth);


 $count = 0;
 $result = array();

while($row = mysql_fetch_object($rec))
  {
     $count++;
     array_push($result, $row);
  }
  // If result matched $myusername and $mypassword, table row must be 1 row

if($count == 1) {

  echo json_encode($result);
  return 1;

}else{
  echo "No results found";
  return 0;
}
```

On $input i have for example "he".

How i can get for example all the rows with this: "HEllo sir", "My HEarth", "like xxHExx"?

It only gets strings like "xxHExx" and "HE" but nothing else...

Actually LIKE operator is not working... How can i get this done with php to get all the strings matching this 2 letters?

Thx

Quick example:

I want to get all the rows that match "ol"

In table data, 2 rows match "ol" in column "titulo"

The value in these columns (titulo) is:
  - "Hola"
  - "Hola2"

So actually the LIKE operation is not giving any resoult in this example...

Comment: In  your code, you will ONLY print a result if zero or one result is found. Wouldn't you like to get more than 1 result?

Comment: i'm guessing what @kainaw pointed out is your problem, cause like should just work fine. also please switch over to mysqli instead of mysql functions. mysql functions are deprecated.

Comment: also you're vulnerable to sql injection

Comment: First read about SQL injection

Comment: yes but the main problem is that LIKE operator is not finding anything, let me edit and add a simple example

Comment: @ManelAlonso How do you know it isn't finding anything? If it finds 2 or 3 or 4 rows, you don't print anything.

Comment: @ManelAlonso Your "Quick Example" will not give a result because you have two rows and you ONLY give a result if you get one row. Please focus on the problem: You are only printing a result if you get one and only one row.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

```
if($count == 1) {
```

to

```
if($count>0) {
```

And...

STOP using mysql_ functions

And...

Learn about SQL Injection

And...

Learn how to use prepared statements

Comment: Okay this is actually working! Thx m8, also don't worry about not using mysqli, it's just a school project :D

Comment: @ManelAlonso i assume you're going to school to later put it into practice for real projects? why not teach yourself the correct way now?

Comment: @RyanVincent that's the way educaton works, it takes 5 years or so for any education establishment (including Universities) to use even remotely current technology. It all moves too fast for them

Comment: Guys xD, i'm not learning PHP on the school, it's a school project cuz i'm going to present it, but they don't teach me anything, it's all by myself. But don't worry, i know how sql injection works and i know how to prevent it. Thanks all